# AppleScript - Help with Safari

Tags: applescript

I've been appointed the task of creating an applicaton that must

1. Display a dialog saying `"The webpage has finished loading."` when a webpage finishes loading
2. Determine how many items are currently in the process of downloading

For number 1, I've tried doing `if the URL of the front document is "http://applescript.weebly.com" then`, but the `then` part always runs even if the webpage doesn't load!

For number 2, I've tried this...

```
tell application "Safari" to get every item of window "Downloads"
```

But this returns references to **every** item, even the ones that havae already been downloaded!

Conclusion: I need help. :S

Answer (score 1):

> Display a dialog saying `"The webpage has finished loading."` when a webpage finishes loading.

There is no way to do this with just pure AppleScript. However, you can use a combination of AppleScript and javascript...

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat until (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is "complete"
    end repeat
    display dialog "The webpage has finished loading."
end tell
```

**WARNING:** If the webpage doesn't load for some reason, the script will be stuck forever in an infinite repeat loop.

---

> Determine how many items are currently in the process of downloading.

When you download files, they are temporarily given the name extension `download`, so AppleScript can tell the Finder to get the files with that extension and create an alert/dialog:

```
set the download_count to 0
set the download_folder to (path to downloads folder) as alias --or wherever the items are being downloaded
tell application "Finder" to set the download_count to the count of (every item of the download_folder whose name extension is "download")
if the download_count is 0 then
    display dialog "There are currently no downloads in progress."
else if the download_count is 1 then
    display dialog "There is currently one download in progress."
else
    display dialog "There are currently " & the download_count & " downloads in progress."
end if
```

---

**P.S.** Thanks for honoring my web site!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the script below in AppleScript Editor to open my browser, display my ISP in the URL, go through the login process and connect to the internet.  Is working perfectly. I want to add or modify it to ping "www.google.com" every hour or so, and if my connection has dropped to repeat the process below again, which will connect my computer back to the internet.

I'm just learning this script writing thing and don't have a very good undersatnding of how it works yet, so if anyone can help please expalin it in simple terms for me.  Very much appreciated.

tell application "Safari"

```
activate

tell application "System Events"
    open location "https://basrah.uswicom.com/login.php"

    delay 1
    keystroke return

    delay 3
    keystroke tab

    keystroke (ASCII character 29)
    delay 1

    delay 1
    keystroke tab

    delay 1
    keystroke "123456789"

    delay 1
    keystroke return

    delay 1
    keystroke return

end tell
```

end tell